# JMeter - Visualize response time using Server Timing API

Tags: jmeter, server-timing

I'm using jmeter for some load testing. I'm interested in both metrics:

- The total response time.
- The db query time.

As usual, my request does the following: hit the server, makes some computation, query the database, makes more computation, and then return a response. I'm interested on measuring the time it takes to resolve the query and visualize it on JMeter.

To do this, I'm using the Server Timing Response API, that is, I'm setting a header on my responses to annotate that time. Something like this:

```
Server-Timing: miss, db;dur=53, app;dur=47.2
```

For more information, checkout the [official documentation](https://web.dev/custom-metrics/?utm_source=devtools#server-timing-api). Now, my problem is that I do not if that is even possible with JMeter. I thought that maybe on a JSR223 listener I can do that, but I'm not sure. Any idea how to take those values and represent them in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can extract it using a suitable Post-Processor like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

   [image]

   it will extract value `53` from the response and store it into `dbdur` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. The next step is declaring this `dbdur` as the [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables), it can be done by i.e. adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=dbdur
   ```

   More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
3. And finally you can plot the variable value as a custom chart in the HTML Reporting Dashboard like it's described in [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) chapter, just change example `ts-hit` sample variable value to your `dbdur` and amend axis/chart titles accordingly.